# Card layout issue

Tags: extjs6

Card layout is display to top right of the application. I need to make it to appear center of the screen.

I have tried setting up the layout

align: 'center'
&
pack: 'center'

No go.

```js
Ext.define('DataARCH.view.data.RestConnectionPopup', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.restConnectionPopup',
//    autoShow: 'true',
//    bodyStyle: {
//        background: 'white'
//    },
//    height: 460,
//    width: 380,
//    title: config.BRAND_SHORT + ' Publisher: REST Connection',
//    constrain: true,
//    resizable: false,
    controller: 'publishdatacontrol',
    initComponent: function () {

        //Card Layout
        console.log("helo");

        var cards = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            requires: ['Ext.layout.container.Card'],
            layout:
                    {
                        type: 'card',
                        align: 'center'
                        //pack: 'center'
                    },
            region: 'center',
            width: 600,
            height: 200,
            bodyPadding: 15,

            defaults: {
                border: false
            },
            defaultListenerScope: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my removing the following lines.

renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
region: 'center',
width: 600,
height: 200